# Is there a way to return document ID by checking field values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a Firebase cloud function and would like to get the ID of a document from a collection by checking it's key values.

I have a collection with several documents. Each document has a unique company_number which is different from the document ID. I would like to get the document ID and store it in a constant.

```
  const company_id = admin.firestore()
  .collection('company_collection')
  .where('company_number', '==', 'company_number')
```

I know my code is wrong but dont know how to correct it. I am new to Firebase and any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: “I know my code is wrong”: in which sense it is wrong? Also, what exactly is the second `'company_number'` in `.where('company_number', '==', 'company_number')`? The value of the desired company number?

Comment: There is no second company number. just the one. I would like to get the document ID if the company_number field matches the 'company_number' I provide

Comment: Then Dharmaraj's answer should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `company_number` is unique to each document so you can read ID of first document in the returned QuerySnapshot as shown below:

```
const companyDoc = await admin.firestore()
  .collection('company_collection')
  .where('company_number', '==', 'company_number')
  .get()

// Check if that 1 doc is returned
if (companyDoc.empty) return "Document Not Found"

const company_id = companyDoc.docs[0].id
```